# ParseException when using SimpleDateFormat.parse("yyyy-MM-dd")

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing, parseexception

My code looks as follows:

```
 (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse("0000-12-25")
```

This argument is supposed to pass a date object to a constructor, but I get a ParseException. I tried playing around with `Locale.US` and `Locale.ENGLISH`, no luck.

Eclipse isn't giving me details on the ParseException, I tried putting the Locale as the second parameter in the SimpleDateFormat declaration.

The idea is to get this:

```
 Date parameter = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse("0000-12-25");
```

so I can call a constructor:

```
NewClass newObject = new NewClass(parameter);
```

but have the parameter creation directly in the constructor call.

Comment: What is the full exception? Also, **how** did you play around with Locale? And, what result do you want (e.g. why so many parenthesis)?

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me

Comment: Unable to reproduce: See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/iJpgP0). I even tried all time zones. No error, so not a DST issue.

Comment: There isn’t a year 0, so it seems to me that what you are trying to do is nonsense. On my Java 10 too your code runs, though, and produces a `parameter`of `Sat Dec 25 00:00:00 CET 1`. That’s right, year 1 since there is no year 0; it’s probably year 1 BCE.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Side note to @ElliottFrisch: I too tend to prefer the redundant parentheses around the instantiation in this case. The space after `new` separates visually, so I find they help reading the expression correctly (the other and possibly even better solution is to use a local variable for the `SimpleDateFormat`).

Comment: @OleV.V. When I posted my comment, the code looked like `..., (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse("0000-12-25"), ...` - which made me wonder what the `...`(s) were.

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess: You wanted to give us a minimal, complete and verifiable example instead of a snippet from your production code out of context. Very nice indeed. In your attempts to do so, you happened to make the example just a little bit too minimal so that it is no longer verifiable. The following code snippet does throw the exception you report:

```
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        Date parameter = dateFormat.parse("0000-12-25");
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        System.out.println(pe);
    }
```

Output:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "0000-12-25"

This is because there is no year 0. A `SimpleDateFormat` with default settings (as used in your question) doesn’t care and just gives us the year before year 1 CE, which is year 1 BCE. A non-lenient `SimpleDateFormat`, however, does care and throws an exception.

Let me further guess, you also didn’t care and would be happy to get the year before year 1.

```
    LocalDate parameter = LocalDate.parse("0000-12-25");
    System.out.println("parameter: " + parameter);
```

> parameter: 0000-12-25

I was going to recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, anyway. And this does use a year zero: 1 BCE is called 0, 2 BCE is -1, etc. And since your date is in ISO 8601 format, the standard that the modern classes use as their default, `LocalDate` parses your string without any explicit formatter.

You needed to pass your date to the `NewClass` constructor. My first recommendation is of course that also in `NewClass` you use the modern `LocalDate` rather than the old, outdated and poorly designed `Date`. Then just pass the above `parameter` as constructor argument. If you cannot change `NewClass` or don’t want to do it just now (is there any better time?), you may convert like this:

```
    Instant startOfDay = parameter.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(startOfDay);
    System.out.println("parameter as Date: " + oldfashionedDate);
```

> parameter as Date: Mon Dec 27 00:09:40 CET 1

When it prints year 1, it is year 1 BCE. `Date.toString` does not print era. And oops, the date is suddenly 2 days off because `Date` and `LocalDate` do not agree 100 % about leap years this far back in history. Which is correct I cannot tell.